# bing map integration for python-django project

Tags: python, django, bing

I am building a webapp which includes displaying the location on bing map. But i cant find any solution or examples of python  for making a marker on bing map, with the specified latitude and longitude or address.

So how will i do it with python in django framework?

or is it possible with javascript..?

(help me with some sample codes,am new to python and django)

Comment: Bing is providing Rest apis please take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx,sometimes this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think for Bing maps they call it Pushpin. Here's the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx